# Initializing Form Controls

Tags: c#, initialization, controls

I have a dialog box in my program where a user can change certain settings. When the form is closed, the changes are stored in the app's settings file.

Every time the dialog loads, the settings are restored in the constructor of the form. This creates a problem: the `CheckedChanged` event (in the case of a checkbox as an example) will always be triggered by the time the form fully opens, without the user doing anything!

I have not tried this, but it is my guess one way to overcome this problem would be to pull the initial statuses of the controls in the designer under Data->Application Settings. But this approach requires a separate setting for every control - not practical due to the large number of controls being one problem.

Is there a (better) way to pre-initialize controls on a form without triggering the `CheckedChange` event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a class-level variable called `IsFormLoading`. Set it to True at the beginning of your constructor, then set it to False at the end, after all the controls have been initialized and settings have been restored.

Each of the events on the form that you don't want to be triggered could check `if (IsFormLoading)` and just `return;`.

Comment: Better hope nothing in-between setting that variable happens asynchronously. The flag would become pretty useless otherwise.

Comment: @Grant: I tried your solution, it works perfect and required minimal changes to code. Thumbs up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have event subscriptions in `InitializeComponent()` method, something the following line :

```
private void InitializeComponent() {
  ...
  this.checkBox1.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.checkBox1_CheckedChanged);
  ...
}
```

and that you restored the form's settings after the `InitializeComponent()` method is called in your constructor.

If so, why not try to defer the event subscriptions after all the controls are fully initialized with your saved settings. Remove all event subscription (*Event += Handler*) from `InitializeComponent()` and place it after the settings are restored.

```
class Form1 : Form {
  public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent(); // remove event subscriptions from InitializeComponent
    ApplySettings();  // restore settings
    AttachEventHandlers(); // subscribe to events here
  }
}
```

Comment: Your assumptions are correct. This solution is probably the most robust, but it is a little bit of an overkill for what I need. Definitely a good approach for serious projects.

Answer (score 0):

So the basic over-view is the pop-up shows, user checks some boxes, closes the form, and changes are saved right?

First question: If your just saving the current state of the controls (checked, not-checked,etc), why even deal with the CheckedChange event? Why not just save all the values of the controls in the Form.FormClosing event? I mean I understand the changed event is called because you are setting the values controls in the form load event, but why bother with the changed event unless you are doing something when the change event is fired??

If you really want to use the CheckedChange event though to perform some actions then you could use a counter like so (top of my head code so may be a little buggy):

```
 private int _loadCount;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
     _loadCount = 0;
     //Code to load values for controls...
}


private void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   _loadCount++;
   if(_loadCount > 1)
  {
   //Do something here...
  }
  else
  {
   //Do nothing, return false, etc...
  }

}
```

In any case, AFAIK the controls changed event always fires regardless of how the controls value was changed (user click, via code, etc).

Comment: Yes this would work. But I think it is a variation on a subject that Grant proposed earlier.